# How to prevent Android SQLite from dumping stack trace to logcat?

Tags: android, sqlite, stack-trace, logcat

On Android 2.3.3 I'm doing a bulk import into one of my SQLite tables, using the API method:

SQLiteDatabase.insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)

It works fine, but if there is a database error with any row (e.g. constraint error) a full stack trace is written to Android Logcat which quickly fills up.

How can I turn off this stack trace?

I already handle any Exception being thrown but the Logcat is being polluted from within the SQLite library code.

I am worried about performance on mobile devices.

- transactions for import are enabled already
- preloaded DB is impossible because data might change

Constraints should be enforced and I will handle violation, but 20 line stack traces in Logcat for each violation multiplied by hundreds of violations is what I want to turn off.

Unfortunately I also cannot use advanced conflict handling introduced with Android Froyo because app must also run on older devices.

Cheers.

Comment: better is to fix the error itself maybe

Comment: Meanwhile I found the solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I just found the solution as follows:

I have to use a different API method (not `SQLiteDatabase.insert()`):

```
SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

Now, the exception is thrown from the SQLite library, as expected and no stack trace is dumped.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out any stuff you're not interested in, based on the tag or the process ID. You can do it easily in the Logcat viewer in Eclipse, or if you're using Logcat on the command line [the instructions are here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html).

Comment: Thanks, but as I said above I am worried about the performance on actual mobile devices, not in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pollution. It's the purpose of LogCat to register everything that's going on on the device / emulator.

If you want to filter out your LogCat, it's possible in Eclipse (you can filter by log tag, by pid, or by log level), thus providing a way to "remove" unwanted exceptions from a LogCat window.

**EDIT** If the issue is performance (according to your comments), I don't think you should worry.

- If you find bad performances, you'll gain A LOT more by enabling transactions on your batch insert.
- Also, if it's to insert "starting data" for your application, have you considered shipping the apk with a pre-loaded database? Instead of inserting everything at run-time, you could just copy an existing database that you prepared yourself. No constraint problem anymore, and almost instant start for your users. Of course, if it's dynamic batch insert (based on user entry or external parameters defined at runtime), it's not possible.

Comment: But I am worried about the performance on actual handsets. It surely costs time and resources to dump a complete stack trace to Logcat.

I am talking about bulk import, hundreds of rows might violate constraints which I want to ignore.

The way it behaves now, in that case hundreds of stack traces are written to Logcat, each stack trace consisting of 20 lines or so.

Comment: Just a thought: if you want to ignore the constraint, why do you have it in the first place? Surely if it's there, it's meant to be enforced, isn't it? But anyway, I don't think you should worry about performance impact on actual devices, unless you intend to run it on a phone from 1995 ;)

Comment: - transactions are enabled already
- preloaded DB impossible because data might change

Constraints should be enforced and I will handle violation, but 20 line stack traces in Logcat for each violation is what I want to turn off.

Comment: Well, arguably, if you have constraints in your db, then a violation of that constraint *should* crash your application

Comment: I beg to disagree, I just log the invalid row IDs for later evaluation. And all other rows are valid data. Why should it crash the app, that would be a bad user experience. Actually I wouldn't mind so much if the constraint violation would just log one line to Logcat, but a full stack trace is too much or at least should be configurable.

Comment: In my experience "later evaluation" never comes, and the program / database remains riddled with invalid data or bugs. Crashing will force you to look at the problem now and fix it. Hopefully before it's available to the users (during UAT or automated testing) - but you're right, there's no absolute rule, you just need to balance the gravity of the constraint violation against the users experience (It could be worse for the users to have invalid data, if it's not then your way is better)

Comment: Just to clarify: I work as an independant developer, mostly for the finance industry. In here, data quality is of utmost importance, and it's a lot preferable (although it's not great, of course) to crash the application than to let bad data silently be available to the users.

Comment: Well my app is just an info app, initial data being provided by third parties through web services, so it can be inconsistent and I have no influence on that. So it's much better to display 99% of the data which is correct rather than crash because of 1% incorrect data.